# Exception using JSON.decode

Tags: json, dart

I'm getting this exception when using JSON.decode in Dart.  Any ideas as to how to resolve this?

> message: Class 'List' has no instance method 'codeUnitAt'.

Here is the JSON data it's trying to decode:

> [{_index: supply-desc-index, _type: supply-desc, _id: AVWeP5ZymMsGSnzRy9Kg, _score: 0.37158427, _source: {name: Test 3, description: test bdrwf, uom: EA, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, fireBaseKey: {description: test bdrwf, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, name: Test 3, uom: EA}}}, {_index: supply-desc-index, _type: supply-desc, _id: AVWeQ_56mMsGSnzRy9NG, _score: 0.37158427, _source: {name: Test, description: test 524, uom: EA, ipn: 42141, mpn: 124124, fireBaseKey: {description: test 524, ipn: 42141, mpn: 124124, name: Test, uom: EA}}}, {_index: supply-desc-index, _type: supply-desc, _id: 1, _score: 0.19178301, _source: {name: Test 3, description: test bdrwf, uom: EA, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, fireBaseKey: {description: test bdrwf, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, name: Test 3, uom: EA}}}, {_index: supply-desc-index, _type: supply-desc, _id: AVWeP6FsmMsGSnzRy9Kh, _score: 0.19178301, _source: {name: Test 3, description: test bdrwf, uom: EA, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, fireBaseKey: {description: test bdrwf, ipn: 1412341, mpn: 1234124, name: Test 3, uom: EA}}}]

Comment: To me the error message indicates that the JSON is already decoded.

Comment: Thank you!  That was the issue. I thought it would not be decoded yet.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that the data you gave - if we take it literally - is not valid JSON (it is valid YAML however.)

If all the keys and values were quoted then it would be valid JSON.

(Validated by pasting your data into jsonlint.com and yamllint.com).

Where's that data coming from?

Comment: Uh, I thought JSON was whitespace ignorant.  This *looks* like valid JSON.

Comment: I think he is referring to the keys and other strings not being quoted. I agree with Güthner Zöchbauer above that this looks like a `List` value with `Map`  elements, not a JSON *string*.

Comment: I had the same issue. I wasn't passing a json string. I accidentally passed another type to the decode function